# Simple Architecture for ASP.NET MVC using Database First EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, ef-database-first

**Background**

I am coming from 3 tier architecture of ASP.NET background. I have used Unit Tests directly on layers and never tried mocking of layers. All application are developed with EF Database First and separate POCOs and Infrastructure project handles the plumbing work of the application. Applications developed are of small to medium size.

**Progress so far**

Since I started learning ASP.NET MVC, One of the first questions was to how to create layers for solution. For last 15 days I am learning and hunting for good architecture to learn and follow in this and future MVC projects. I have went through following architecture patterns/sites and found them too complex for my own good. Some of the main concerns

- Inherit complexity of the project which makes it difficult to work with for new programmers
- Sharp learning curve
- Too many unit tests for every layer to test redundant behaviors (minor)
- Relatively slow compilation during development

**Sites / Project I tried**

- Sharp Architecture
- Onion Architecture
- Neard Dinner
- Project SiLK (Microsoft)

**Main Dilemmas**

- I found that most common thing among these projects is Repository Patterns and Dependency Injection (IoC). Though I do not have anything against it, I found it hard to maintain and understand projects. I have executed fairly large projects with 3 tier architecture, with so-called "tight coupling" with adequate Unit tests to test the project. I feel architecture will be better off without these involved.
- Huge emphasis on TDD and DDD
- Concept of loosely coupled is far stretched
- Loosing focus on MVC as pattern and dominating architecture with other parts

**Required** Simple, easy to understand, **maintainable** architecture for MVC projects

Note: I came across this good implementation structure from jimmy bogard’s [Organizing ASP.NET MVC solutions](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/09/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions/). I would still appreciate any suggestions on this topic.

Comment: An design I became very fond of the last few years is one that uses a few very well selected generic abstractions which makes it very easy to plug in cross cutting concerns using generic decorators. For instance, take a look at this [article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: All the things you are concerned about are the main reasons to use MVC over webforms etc. "Architechture" will not be better without these. DI Allows loose coupling. MVC allows loosely coupled code, TDD encourages loosely coupled code. The main cost in software development for most projects is maintenance so  I'd suggest looking at learning TDD and making your code as loosely coupled as possible. You bold maintainable if you want that learn to use DI/TDD etc. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Agree with Steven - architecture he outlines works amazingly well in medium->large scale application. It makes an application highly testable and highly configurable, we support 15 customers all with different implementations of various parts. We added ICommandValidator<T> for validating commands before being sent, and IModelEnrciher<T> to deal with populating certain properties of ViewModels. Bit of AutoMapper ViewResults and it is very easily maintained

Answer (score 0):

> Required Simple, easy to understand, maintainable architecture for MVC
>   projects

Go for [NidoFramework](https://nidoframework.codeplex.com). It is just what you are looking for. It is free, simple, well design code framework with a good architectural pattern.

I must say [Nido framework](https://nidoframework.codeplex.com) will hit the head of the nail for you for your requirement..

Link: https://nidoframework.codeplex.com

Download from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NidoFramework/)

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

After so much of looking backward and forward I have settled on using Onion Architecture for my ASP.NET MVC WebAPI project.

In this course I found my self struggling to keep up with new development methodologies and frameworks. Fact is whoever is looking for creating new application based on three tier structure or similar existing structure, need to "let go" and embrace new foundations. Advances in the new development philosophies like TDD and BDD are immense and are nothing but helpful.

Web and supported technologies are different beasts than that I know of. Truth is MVC and MVC WebAPI got developed cause existing Web Forms framework could not keep up with new developments.

**Technology Stack**

It took time and patience to unlearn and learn. But finally I find myself at new level and with the flow of mainstream developments. Following is final technology stack adopted by me (in no particular order).

Backend

- ASP.net MVC WebPI
- Onion Architecture
- EF database first (cause it was suited for my project)
- Generic Repositories

Frontend

- Bootstrap UI (as UI design framework and skipped jQuery UI)
- Typescript (for strongly typed JavaScript, so no direct JS in project)
- AngularJS (as front-end MVC)
- LESS CSS (for robust and maintainable CSS, so no direct CSS in project)
- Breeze.js (for model binding and change tracking)

Testing
 - In process of finalizing

Along with above I have used and created bunch of T4 templates to take care of redundant tasks. I would suggest master yourself in it. It reduces development time considerably. I am still making my mind for some of the tools and project and testing. I will post the finalized stack of it once am done.

Above stack may look comprehensive but I found myself it as necessity to built highly maintainable and responsive web application. As I mentioned before, it takes time, but once you are familiar with it, it makes sense.
Note: Of all, learning curve of AngularJS very steep and you will find yourself going back and forth on decision to use it. But stick to it, its worth it.

@Steven: Thanks a bunch for your link, it really was corner stone for me to unravel mysteries of new Web.